# How to play Youtube video in ExoPlayer in Android Studio

Tags: exoplayer

my app uses exoplayer but when adding youtube link the player doesn't work, here is my code.

````
```
public void initVideoPlayer(String url, String type) {
    if (player != null) {
        player.release();
    }

    progressBar.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
    BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
    TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory = new
            AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);

    TrackSelector trackSelector = new
            DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);

    player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance((Context) PlayerActivity.this, trackSelector);
    exoPlayerView.setPlayer(player);
    // below 2 lines will make screen size to fit
    exoPlayerView.setResizeMode(AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_FILL);
    player.setVideoScalingMode(C.VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT_WITH_CROPPING);
    exoPlayerView.setControllerShowTimeoutMs(5000);
    player.setPlayWhenReady(true);

    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);

    switch (type) {
        case "hls":
            mediaSource = hlsMediaSource(uri, PlayerActivity.this);
            break;
       /*case "youtube":
            extractYoutubeUrl(url, PlayerActivity.this, 18);
            break;
        case "youtube-live":
            extractYoutubeUrl(url, PlayerActivity.this, 133);
            break;*/
        case "rtmp":
            mediaSource = rtmpMediaSource(uri);
            break;
        default:
            mediaSource = mediaSource(uri, PlayerActivity.this);
            break;
    }

    if (!type.contains("youtube")) {
        player.prepare(mediaSource, true, false);
        exoPlayerView.setPlayer(player);
        player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    }

    seekToStartPosition();

    player.addListener(new Player.DefaultEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
            if (playWhenReady && playbackState == Player.STATE_READY) {
                isPlaying = true;
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                //create media session
                // mediaSessionHelper = new MediaSessionHelper(player, PlayerActivity.this, model, isPlaying);
                // mediaSessionHelper.updateMetadata();
                //mediaSessionHelper.updatePlaybackState();

            } else if (playbackState == Player.STATE_READY) {
                isPlaying = false;
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                //add watch next card
                long position = player.getCurrentPosition();
                long duration = player.getDuration();
                /*mediaSessionHelper.updateMetadata();
                mediaSessionHelper.updatePlaybackState();*/

            } else if (playbackState == Player.STATE_BUFFERING) {
                isPlaying = false;
                progressBar.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                player.setPlayWhenReady(true);

            } else if (playbackState == Player.STATE_ENDED) {
                //remove now playing card
                //mediaSessionHelper.stopMediaSession();
                 } else {
                // player paused in any state
                isPlaying = false;
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    });

    exoPlayerView.setControllerVisibilityListener(new PlayerControlView.VisibilityListener() {
        @Override
        public void onVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
            visible = visibility;
        }
    });
}
```
````

I am trying to play youtube video in exoplayer but here is some confusion I don't know what is DASH url, I have only real youtube url like "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v1uyQZNg2vE" , I have no idea how to generate dash url form real url.

Comment: https://www.yout-ube.com/watch?v=v1uyQZNg2vE

Comment: Not sure thats what u need. Says video is unavailable